# To what extent is hardly a negative adverb?

Tags: adverbs, negation

The American Heritage Dictionary notes about adverbs like *hardly* that

> they are not truly negative in meaning.  The sentence *Mary hardly laughed* means that Mary did laugh a little, not that she kept from laughing altogether, and therefore does not express a negative proposition.

However, they are similar to negative adverbs in that they combine with *any* and *at all*, as in “I hardly saw him at all.”

With this in mind, which sentence below would be correct?

> *A) Putin is **hardly** popular among Germans, but **so** is the prospect of a scrap with Russia on Ukraine’s behalf.*

> *B) Putin is **hardly** popular among Germans, but **neither** is the prospect of a scrap with Russia on Ukraine’s behalf.*

[Source for (A):  ‘Was Ukraine Betrayed at Geneva?’ by Rajan Menon, https://nationalinterest.org/feature/was-ukraine-betrayed-geneva-10272]

I would say (B), since the idea could be paraphrased as follows:  Putin is not popular, but neither is war with Russia.  But would this be true for any compound sentence where the first clause contains *hardly?*  Or would it depend on whether *hardly* is indicating a truly negative quality or a minimally positive one?

Answer (score 5):

Well, as you point out, *hardly* is a negative trigger.
I.e, it can license ***[Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)*** in construction with it.
*Any* and *at all* are NPIs, but there are lots more in English.

Checking out the negative strength of *hardly* (as shown in [this freshman-level puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIsquish.pdf)),
we find that it works with some NPIs

- *I hardly have **any** ~ I hardly **ever** do it ~ He hardly **budged** ~ He hardly has **a red cent***.
- *He's hardly done it **in weeks** ~ They'll hardly arrive **until** noon ~ I hardly have **much** time.*

but not so well with others

- *?He's hardly arrived **yet** ~ ?You hardly **need** stare at him*
- *?I hardly **dare** disturb him.* ~ *?It will hardly **take long***

and with still others, it's terrible; both of the following are ungrammatical, for instance:

- **I hardly saw people there to speak of*
- **I would hardly mind fighting with her*

So, to **that** extent *hardly* is a negative.
It's a strange word, and shares this level of negativity with *seldom, rarely,* and *scarcely*.

Comment: Thanks - these examples show some of the ambiguities.  ‘Sarah hardly laughed at all’ is fine, but ‘Sarah hardly laughed, and neither did I’ seems odd.  I don’t see a pattern.

Comment: Importantly, it would normally cause the sentence to take a *positive* question tag: *There were people there, **weren't there**?* versus *there were hardly any people there, **were there**?* This also seems to show that *hardly* is negative.

Comment: Ah, but the plural doesn't happen in a contraction _There's hardly any people there, isn't there?_, which reminds me of Indian English _There's hardly any people there, isn't it?_

Answer (score 3):

If you check at say AHD, you will see that different senses are given for 'hardly'. Where I start to worry about their treatment is that they lump all of these usages in the 'adverb' catch-all, even though the distributions are easily separable.

**Mary hardly laughed** in the usually understood sense ('Mary hardly laughed at all') certainly has 'hardly' associated with the verb 'laugh(ed)', but I'd say this is not a true adverbial modification (saying something more about the manner say of laughing) but telling us more about the limits of the action. It seems to be the verb-related analogue of 'a determiner rather than an adjective', referencing the context of the verb rather than truly modifying it.  I'd class it as a limiting modifier here. Compare 'John almost died'.

On the other hand, **Putin is hardly popular among Germans** uses 'hardly' as a modal pragmatic marker being dismissive of / assigning near-zero probability to the statement in the main clause (as seen by the rewrites 'Putin - popular among Germans? Hardly!' or 'One could hardly say that Putin is popular among Germans). The first rewrite possibly strengthens my claim that the correct alternative here is [B]:

Putin is hardly popular among Germans, but [then] neither is the prospect of a scrap with Russia on Ukraine’s behalf.

Comment: Yes, in the Putin example ‘hardly’ is functioning as an emphatic negative, like ‘of course not,’ so the NPI ‘neither’ is appropriate.

Comment: Yet whichever sense is meant, ‘hardly’ still seems to act as a negative trigger (the essence of my question, I think.)

Comment: John Lawler gives a fine analysis, and gives a judiciously hedged summary.