# question tags with or responses to "Seldom/Rarely/hardly" statements?

Tags: adverbs, negation, question-tags

We have had questions and answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64646/question-tags-did-you-vs-didnt-you) and [elsewhere](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26239/agreement-with-so-and-neither/26241#26241) about how to properly question-tag or respond to normal statements like

> *I go to the store on Tuesdays*
>   *I hate mushrooms*

and to "negative-polarity" statements like

> *I never go to the store on Tuesdays*
>    *I don't hate mushrooms*.

There are also claims that *hardly* is a negative-polarity indicator, particularly at [To What Extent is *Hardly* a negative Adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165532/to-what-extent-is-hardly-a-negative-adverb)

However, as noted at that question, *hardly* is a strange word, and in particular, I suddenly have cause to wonder how *hardly* (and its compatriots in strangeness, *rarely* and *seldom*) work with tag questions and agreements.  Beyond the stated links (and some of the links out from those), however, I have found precious little information on dealing with these words, and precisely nothing on how they affect tag questions and responses.

To my ear, all of these sound wrong as tag questions/responses:

> He seldom goes there, <sup>?</sup>doesn't he?
>   He seldom goes there, <sup>?</sup>does he?
>
> He seldom goes there.  <sup>?</sup>—neither do I/Me neither.
>   He seldom goes there.  <sup>?</sup>—so do I/Me too.
>
> He seldom goes there.  <sup>?</sup>—But I do.

(You can substitute *rarely* or *hardly ever* with the same effect in those examples.)

So, is there a correct tag question or simple response form for these sorts of statements?  Is my ear wrong, and some of these formats are accepted?  Or is my default reply of "Same here" or a full-sentence counter (e.g. "Oh, I go there pretty regularly") the norm?

Comment: Am I right? and Am I wrong? mean virtually the same thing for an either/or question(half empty/half full). "Neither" means two things compared are have the same quality. Neither essentially be replaced with "also", as can "so" or "too". If you also do what the person does it doesn't matter if you're agreeing with a negative or a positive? 'But' is the opposite of 'also' so using 'but' you must disagree with the first statement. I don't think the seldom or rarely or hardly are pertinent at al; it's only the "also" or "opposite"(but,however,in contrast etc) that matter?(thoughts,not formal ans)

Comment: _I go to the store on Tuesdays_ is not a positive polarity sentence. It's just a sentence. There is a real "positive polarity", however, which one finds in phrases like _would rather_ or _sort of_, which don't work in negative contexts, only positive. That said (and it's merely a matter of terminology), you're absolutely right about _hardly_ -- it's a very strange word.

Comment: My kids would agree with *I know, right?* I'm not sure I have a better answer in adult-speak than your suggestions. I do think that *hardly ever* sounds better to my ear with the negative-polarity responses than *rarely* or *seldom*...maybe because of the *ever*? But  *It hardly matters, does it?* sounds perfectly fine, even without the *ever*, so maybe not. (I should probably add that *rarely* and *seldom* do NOT sound right to me in that rhetorical sentence.)

Answer (score 3):

> "The adverbs never, rarely, seldom, hardly, barely and scarcely have a negative sense. Even though they may be in a positive statement, the feeling of the statement is negative. We treat statements with these words like negative statements, so the question tag is normally positive."  *[from the English Club article linked below]*

Thus:

- I never go to the store on Tuesdays, do I? [positive tag]
- I don't hate mushrooms, do I?  [positive tag]
- He seldom goes there, does he?  [positive tag]
- He seldom goes there; and neither do I.  [neither extension]
- He seldom goes there; but I do.  [conjunction "but" + subordinate clause]

Sources:
[EnglishClub.com's page on Tag Questions](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/tag-questions.htm) (Look under: "Special Cases -- Negative adverbs.")
[English Grammar: An Introduction (3rd edition)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ydXwDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=hardly%20rarely%20seldom%20grammar%20neither%20does%20he%20do%20they&source=bl&ots=LhuworXBvV&sig=NJUQJfv3Dn5FbSiLv-U2z47mQT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwict_LVofjTAhXoxlQKHaj1AGIQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=hardly%20rarely%20seldom%20grammar%20neither%20does%20he%20do%20they&f=false) at Google Books
[Writing in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=QmJV3_MytJMC&pg=PT53&dq=but%20conjunction%20subordinate%20clause&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd0K3Ko_jTAhVWzGMKHVwSA4gQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=but%20conjunction%20subordinate%20clause&f=false) at Google Books

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/607837/2085).